# Sync Offline DB With DB On Server

Tags: android

Hi I was wondering how you'd approach solving the following problem when developing for android:

1. The app checks whether the user has an internet connection
2. if there is no connection the app stores the current data in the localdb
3. once an internet connection is established it then syncs with a webservice

I'm just not too familiar with that check and the process of when I could sync etc
Cheers